Making rainfall charts using QGIS
I am using QGIS for the first time and really struggling to get it to show anything apart from a few dots on a white screen.
In May of this year my home county experienced a really wet 24hr period. I have all the rainfall data for that day and the all rainfall station coordinates etc in a CSV file. I have downloaded this data as a new layer but really that's as far as I can manage, a white screen with numerous dots.
How could I see at least a map, or even better join up the dots into areas of equal rainfall?
Edit - some text from the CSV file
Station,Northing,Easting,Rainfall
Crew Fell,355892,577427,8.2
Abbeytown,315903,551386,61.2
Aisgill  ,377863,496341,47.1
Barras,384468,512126,53.5
Beetham,349887,479084,59.6




Station
Northing
Easting
Rainfall




Crew Fell
355892
577427
8.2


Abbeytown
315903
551386
61.2


Aisgill
377863
496341
47.1


Barras
384468
512126
53.5


Beetham
349887
479084
59.6




can you give an example of your csv file? is the coordinates the same location?

I have uploaded the CSV file here https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/ikez0clu6dlny9gk3lrni/May22nd-Rainfall-event-2024.csv?rlkey=db2ydppq8jxqy4mndz52paorm&st=mjd8gjan&dl=0

Reading this should get you in the right direction : https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/gentle_gis_introduction/spatial_analysis_interpolation.html

Your coordinates headings are reversed/incorrect. Eastings are X and Northings are Y coords but if I specify that when adding the CSV to QGIS the points end up in Norfolk.  Change your CSV header to Station,Easting,Northing,Rainfall.

Re. "white screen" have you added a basemap? Something like OpenStreetMap XYZ tiles which you can add manually or via the QuickMapServices plugin.

Re. "see at least a map, or even better join up the dots into areas of equal rainfall" what exactly do you want to see? Rainfall contours? Interpolating rainfall data between weather stations isn't trivial.  You could change layer-properties-symbology from single symbol to graduated colours.

Thanks for your help, I have switched Eastings and northings around.  ideally I would like to see rainfall contours. All  I have now is the blue graduated dots on a white screen. Im unable to get a basemap to show

I am looking to create a Rainfall Isohyetal map/chart. If I can get it working - My knowledge of QGIS is very limited, infact zero. Just an amateur weather enthusiast.

These are the rough steps you'll want to follow:
Getting the data into QGIS
It sounds like you already got this done, but for completeness I'll include this step as well.
There are various ways to achieve this, I'd recommend going via the menu Layer / Add Layer / Add Delimited Text Layer. Choose your file and open the Geometry Definition section. Use the following settings:

You can select the Geometry CRS (the coordinate system used by the coordinates in your file) by clicking the button to the right of the dropdown.
As has been noted in the comments the X and Y here are strictly speaking "wrong", but once added using these settings that is nothing you have to worry about.
Getting a background map
Next you want some sort of geographic context - you want to see where the points now visible on your map are located in the real world. The easiest way to do so is by adding a background map. There are literally hundreds to choose from, topographic maps with various styles, satellite imagery, etc. Here are a few options for you to play with:
OpenStreetMap
A good start is always OpenStreetMap - it's free to use (just remember to include the proper attribution if you share a map that includes it).
There are two main ways to add it:
Manually
In the Browser (top left panel by default), find XYZ Tiles, right click and choose New Connection. Give the connection a Name (such as "OpenStreetMap") and use the URL https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png (other options are relevant, but not for now). Click OK. You can then drag the OpenStreetMap layer in from the Browser to the map (in case your points now are hidden you can reorder the layers in the Layers panel).
Using QuickMapServices
Alternatively, you can install the plugin called QuickMapServices. Do so using the menu Plugins / Manage and Install Plugins..., search for the plugin and install it using Install Plugin.
Then, once it has installed, go to the menu Web / QuickMapServices / Settings, choose the last tab (More services) and click the button. Close the dialog and go to the menu Web / QuickMapServices / OSM / OSM Standard to add an OpenStreetMap layer.
CartoDB Positron
A personal favourite of mine for background maps, also based on OpenStreetMap data, is CartoDB Positron. You can add it manually (URL https://a.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png) or using QuickMapServices (Web / QuickMapServices / CartoDB / Positron). Same note about attribution applies.
Styling your points
At this point you should have the points with measured rain on map!
Now you can start to make your points prettier, there are various options for this. Get start by opening the Layer Styling panel (View / Panels / Layer Styling Panel).
In the Layer Styling panel, at the top where it currently should say Single Symbol, change it to Graduated. Just below, set Value to Rainfall, then click Classify further down. Your points should now get different colors based on how much it rained there.
Take your time here to play around with the other options, especially the Color ramp, Mode and Classes.
Example of the result:

Generating a isohyetal map
This is a bit outside of what I usually do so there might be better options, but you should get the general idea (and others might point out what can be improved).
First you need to generate a continuous raster of rainfall from your points. You can do so using the built in interpolation algorithms (Inverse Distance Weighted, IDW) or install a plugin for other algorithms (such as Kriging).
For IDW, go to Processing / Toolbox and select Interpolation / IDW interpolation in the panel that opens. Choose the layer with your points, set the Interpolation attribute to Rainfall and click on the green plus. Set the Distance coefficient P to 3 (you might want to play around with it later though*). Click the small arrow on the Extent row and choose Calculate from Layer... and then your point layer. Finally, set the Pixel size X to 100 (can also be adjusted later) and click Run.
You should now get a black/white raster showing rainfall over the entire area. To get isohyetals/contours, find and open Contour in the Toolbox, select your raster and the interval between contour lines (you can start with the default, 10). Click Run, and you'll shortly see your lines.
From there, you can style your lines like you did with the points. You can also label them and do other things.
Here's an example I generated from your data:

* Note that to play around with the settings in the processing tools you have to re-run them, which will generate a new layer. There is no way to change the parameters and see the change on-the-fly as with styling.

Many thanks for a comprehensive reply -  that last map/chart is certainly what I am aiming for !! -  I appear to be a long way off that at the moment.  First off all I cant get the EPSG:2700   -  just cant find that on the list -  so I am stuck at that point so far ?

Just add it like that: https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_projections/working_with_projections.html#custom-coordinate-reference-system

Thanks but that doesnt work for me, over my head completely. I may have to call this quits, its looking like its just generally to complicated.

@PaulC : It is 27700, not 2700! Just enter this number in the CRS selection field, then it should appear at the bottom: you have to expand the section Projected -> Transverse Mercator, see: https://i.sstatic.net/6GIR3RBM.png

Thanks - I have done that and appears to have worked. I still cant see my map unfortunately, just have a white screen ? any thoughts on what I am doing wrong

https://app.box.com/s/om77qgraue8zes6je8pumbtasomd5kyi

@PaulC can you save and share your QGIS project file (.qgz)?

Update -  I now have a map showing but no points

https://app.box.com/s/yus9bqbkk7c6rhhnupxclrw5kpuuyu4f

shared file above ( hopefully)

You're actually very close! Note how, in the Layers panel, you have OpenStreetMap (the background) before your points. This means that the background map will be drawn on top of your points, completely hiding them. Luckily the fix is easy, just drag yours points to above OpenStreetMap (or the other way around) and you'll see your points on the map!

Hi -  Many thanks. I now have a useable chart that makes sense. Finally got somewhere this evening. Thankyou for your help

Can I now go back to the Isohyetal map   I have followed the instructions for that but just getting mostly a black s and grey chart covering the whole map, its completley unreadable. It also took 4 mins to "run" .  I didnt quite understand pixel size to 100, is .100  Point100 100 ? I maybe going very big ?  I cant find contour in the toolbox either, cheers Paul

When you're doing the interpolation you get a raster (think "image"), a regular grid och pixels. The pixel size says how large each pixel is; smaller pixel size means more pixels, larger pixel size means more pixels. In GIS, you often have to do the tradeof of smaller pixels which means higher accuracy but slower processing, and larger pixels that mean lower accuracy but faster processing.
The contour tool is found under GDAL / Raster extraction / Contour.

Jan - I am really struggling, it just doesnt work for me unfortunately. I must be doing something wrong, but I dont know what. I have tried to follow your  help. I have the map with the rainfall dots. Happy with that stage but cant progress into the contour part. My son had a go over the weekend , he manage a few straight lines, but it looked awful. I cant manage to get any lines at all. Processing/Interpolation/IDW Interpolation, change 1,2 to rainfall/Distance Co Eff to 3 ( why 3) Pixel size default is 0.10000, do I change to 100.000 or lower.

Calculate from layer, chose rainfall, press run -  just hangs with 0% complete, I leave it for 5 mins then give him and try again
